# How to create new bookmark type for use with Bookmark+?

Tags: bookmarks, bookmark+

With [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus), we can define our own bookmark types, and list bookmarks by type.  I am not a lisp programmer. Can someone give me an example of how to define a new type, such as **dev** or **web**?

Answer (score 2):

Two answers, depending on what you mean by a bookmark "type":

- The first answer says how to create a new type of bookmark, in the sense of bookmarks that have some specific behavior.
- The second answer speaks to the simple case where all you really want to do is designate a given set of bookmarks as belonging to some category -- the bookmarks don't need any particular behavior. Here, you just *tag* the bookmarks with a name.

---

You have to say what such a bookmark type (dev or web) *is/does*. Any specific behavior it has can't be guessed. And you'll need to code that behavior.

But here's a general recipe.  This will get you the behaviors you see for the predefined Bookmark+ types (except for highlighting your new type specially in the display list).

I'll call your new bookmark type "MYTYPE", here.

*Step 5 is really the answer to your question*, as I understand it. That needs step 4, which needs step 3, which needs step 2, which needs step 1.

- Step 1 makes it possible to identify a MYTYPE bookmark. It gives the bookmark a specific handler function.
- Step 2 creates a bookmark record that uses that handler function.
- Step 3 defines a predicate that returns true if a bookmark is a MYTYPE bookmark -- it just tests whether a bookmark has that type's handler.
- Step 4 defines a function that returns only MYTYPE bookmarks, from all of the bookmarks that are current.
- Step 5 defines a command to show only MYTYPE bookmarks in the bookmark-list display.
- Steps 6 and 7 are optional. They bind the show command to a key and define a MYTYPE-specific jump command.

1. Define a handler function to jump to a MYTYPE bookmark.

```lisp
(defun MYTYPE-bookmark-jump (bookmark)
  "Bookmark handler for MYTYPE bookmarks."
  (;; Code whatever MYTYPE-specific behavior you need.
   ;; ...
   ;; Then invoke the default handler in the current buffer.
   (bookmark-default-handler
    `("" (buffer . ,(current-buffer))
          . ,(bookmark-get-bookmark-record bookmark)))
```

2. Define a function to create a MYTYPE bookmark. The function should be able to be the value of variable `bookmark-make-record-function`.

```lisp
(defun MYTYPE-bookmark-make-record ()
  "Make a MYTYPE bookmark record."
  `(,@(bookmark-make-record-default)
    ;; Whatever MYTYPE-specific properties you want.
    ;; E.g. property foo and its value. 
    (foo . ,(...))
    (handler . MYTYPE-bookmark-jump))) ; The MYTYPE handler.
```

That creates a bookmark record such as this:

```
((filename . "FILE WHERE CREATED")
 (buffer-name . BUFFER WHERE CREATED")
 (front-context-string . "STRING BEFORE CREATION POINT")
 (rear-context-string . "STRING AFTER CREATION POINT")
 (front-context-region-string)
 (rear-context-region-string)
 (visits . 0)
 (time 25447 19436 101446 0)
 (created 25447 19436 101446 0)
 (position . 1282)
 (foo . VALUE-FOR-FOO)    ; Example of a MYTYPE-specific field
 (handler . MYTYPE-bookmark-jump))
```

3. Define a predicate that tests whether a bookmark is of type MYTYPE. It typically just tests the MYTYPE handler.

```lisp
(defun MYTYPE-bookmark-p (bookmark)
  "Return non-nil if BOOKMARK is a MYTYPE bookmark."
  (eq (bookmark-get-handler bookmark) 'MYTYPE-bookmark-jump))
```

4. Define a filter function, which returns only MYTYPE bookmarks.

```lisp
(defun MYTYPE-alist-only ()
  "`bookmark-alist', filtered to retain only MYTYPE bookmarks.
A new list is returned (no side effects)."
  (bookmark-maybe-load-default-file)
  (bmkp-remove-if-not #'MYTYPE-bookmark-p bookmark-alist))
```

5. Use macro `bmkp-define-show-only-command` (from file `bookmark+-mac.el`) to define a command `bmkp-bmenu-show-only-MYTYPE-bookmarks`, to show only bookmarks of type MYTYPE.

```lisp
(bmkp-define-show-only-command
  MYTYPE
  "Display (only) MYTYPE bookmarks."
  MYTYPE-alist-only)
```

6. Bind that show command to a key.  E.g., bind it to `C S`:

```lisp
(define-key bookmark-bmenu-mode-map "CS" 'bmkp-bmenu-show-only-MYTYPE-bookmarks)
```

7. Define a command to jump to a MYTYPE bookmark.
   Use `bmkp-read-bookmark-for-type` in the `interactive` spec, to
   prompt for a MYTYPE bookmark name.  (Or else just use `C-x j :`,
   which prompts you first for the type name - MYTYPE.)

```lisp
(defun MYTYPE-jump (bookmark)
  "Jump to a MYTYPE bookmark."
  (interactive (list (bmkp-read-bookmark-for-type
                       "MYTYPE" (MYTYPE-alist-only))))
  (when (stringp bookmark)
    (setq bookmark  (bmkp-get-bookmark-in-alist
                      bookmark t (MYTYPE-alist-only))))
  (bmkp-jump-1 bookmark 'bmkp--pop-to-buffer-same-window))
```

---

Another possibility is that you don't really need any new bookmark types, e.g. because the bookmarks of the "types" you mention don't have any special behavior/definition.

That is, perhaps all you really mean by "type" is a *name*, that is, a **tag** that you assign to bookmarks you want to consider as being in the same category -- the category being just the tag (name).

For that, you *just tag the bookmarks* the way you want, e.g. with tag **`dev`** or **`web`** (or perhaps with both tags, if you want overlapping categories/types).

Then you can, if you want, *act on only* bookmarks that have one or the other (or both) of those tags.  And you can *sort* the `*Bookmark List*` display according to tags, or *list only* bookmarks tagged a certain way, etc.

For this feature, see [Bookmark Tags](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags).